# checkbox.checked is always false in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am always getting checkbox checked property as a false even if it is checked on gridview.I have tried the other answers on this forum like enableviewstate set to false but didn't worked.
Please help.

Here is my Design

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table class="style1">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            TPA Batch Auditing</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>               
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">               
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView_BatchAuditing" runat="server" Width="80%" 
                EnableModelValidation="True" >
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" EnableViewState="true" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#3399FF" />
            </asp:GridView>               

            <div id="DivNoRec" runat="server">
            <table class="style1" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#3399FF">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#3399FF">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#3399FF">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td bgcolor="#3399FF">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="25%">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <strong>No Record Found</strong></td>
                    <td width="25%">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <asp:Button ID="Button_BatchAuditing" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                Height="44px" onclick="Button_BatchAuditing_Click" Text="BatchAuditing" 
                Width="142px" Font-Size="Small" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

C# code

```
protected void Button_BatchAuditing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in GridView_BatchAuditing.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox cbx = (CheckBox)gvRow.FindControl("CheckBox1");
        if (cbx.Checked == true)
        {     
            //int i=0;
            //my code
            //cbx.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you bind your grid? On Page_Load?

Comment: You need to reference the cell before finding the control

Comment: @IhorDeyneka Yes on Page_Load...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have used isPostback property while binding your data on Page_Load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //code to bind data to gridview
    }

}
```